# Pandas groupby is extremely slow

Tags: python, pandas

Below is my dataframe and the code, as the size of the dataframe increases. THe time taken increase quite significantly. What is wrong? How can this  be vectorized?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'delta_t': np.random.randint(0, 301, 100),
    'specimen': np.random.choice(['X', 'Y', 'Z'], 100),
    'measuremnt': np.random.rand(100),
    'lag': np.random.rand(100)
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Defining the q75 function
def q75(x):
    return x.quantile(0.75)

# Applying the given code
df_result = df.groupby(['specimen', 'delta_t']).agg({
    'measuremnt': ['mean', q75, 'max'],
    'lag': 'mean'
}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Give more details: on what size you start seeing a significant difference in time performance?

Comment: Once the number of rows exceed 25000, I am seeing extreme slowness

Comment: If you compute the aggregations individually and concatenate, do you get a perf improvement?

Comment: Also kindly share the timings

Comment: I think some of that will depend on the server config right and so is not reproducible?

Comment: using ur sample data, with a dataframe of size 300,000, timeit returns 112ms; with a size of 30_000, the timeit returns 94.3ms. I dont see that as too high of a jump, unless there is something else you have in mind

Comment: IIRC, `.agg` is not vectorized across the groups, and is somewhat equivalent to do a `for key, data in df.groupby()`. If speed is a concern, it's faster to do lazy groupby first, and apply the native Pandas function one at a time.

Comment: @QuangHoang is right, and I referred to that earlier. You'll have to test on your code though

Answer (score 3):

As commented, do a lazy groupby like this:

```
%%timeit -n 10
groups = df.groupby(['specimen', 'delta_t'])

df_result = pd.DataFrame({
    'measurement_mean': groups['measuremnt'].mean(),
    'measurement_q75': groups['measuremnt'].quantile(.75),
    'measurement_max': groups['measuremnt'].max(),
    'lag': groups['lag'].mean()
}).reset_index()

> 1.95 ms ± 337 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Output:

```
  specimen  delta_t  measurement_mean  measurement_q75  measurement_max       lag
0        X        9          0.861484         0.861484         0.861484  0.338134
1        X       10          0.675029         0.675029         0.675029  0.573993
2        X       24          0.894738         0.894738         0.894738  0.411725
3        X       41          0.610354         0.610354         0.610354  0.953460
4        X       45          0.271329         0.271329         0.271329  0.931424
```

Compared to your code:

```
%%timeit -n 10
# Applying the given code
df_result = df.groupby(['specimen', 'delta_t']).agg({
    'measuremnt': ['mean', q75, 'max'],
    'lag': 'mean'
}).reset_index()

> 43.2 ms ± 1.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If you want a MultiIndex, pass tuples as keys:

```py
df_result = pd.DataFrame({
    ('measurement','mean'): groups['measuremnt'].mean(),
    ('measurement','q75'): groups['measuremnt'].quantile(.75),
    ('measurement','max'): groups['measuremnt'].max(),
    ('lag','mean'): groups['lag'].mean()
}).reset_index()
```

Comment: But, I am missing 'specimen', 'delta_t' in the df_result column??

Comment: They should still be there, see updated answer for the actual output on my system. What's your Pandas version? Mine is 2.0.3, but I'm pretty sure that should be the case for most.